# Vertex Buffer issues

Tags: c++, opengl

I recently created this VertexBuffer class to and added it to my opengl based engine; but it seems to fail in my main code, causing an "access violation at 0x00000000."...

Here is **VertexBuffer.h** :

```
#pragma once

#include "Type.h"
#include "Tags.h"

namespace Spiky {
namespace GLLayer {

template<>
struct GLObjDelAlloc<Tags::VertexBuffer> {
  static void Allocate(GLTypeCT<GLType::Integer> count,
                       Tags::VertexBuffer::internal* names) {
    glGenBuffers(count, names);
  } 
  static void Delete(GLTypeCT<GLType::Integer> count, Tags::VertexBuffer::internal* names) {
   glDeleteBuffers(count, names);
  }
};
template<>
struct GLObjBind<Tags::VertexBuffer> {
 private:
  static Tags::VertexBuffer::internal _active;
 public:
  static const int ZERO_BUFFER = GL_NONE;
  static void BindRequest(Tags::VertexBuffer::internal name = ZERO_BUFFER) {
    if(_active != name) {
      glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
      _active = name;
    }
  }
};
Tags::VertexBuffer::internal 
 GLObjBind<Tags::VertexBuffer>::_active = 0;

//wrapper around GLObjDelAlloc & GLObjBind
class VertexBuffer {
 public:
  explicit VertexBuffer() {
    GLObjDelAlloc<Tags::VertexBuffer>::Allocate(1, &handle_);
  }
  inline void Bind() {
    GLObjBind<Tags::VertexBuffer>::BindRequest(handle_);
  }

  template<typename T>
  static void BufferData(const GLTypeCT<GLType::Integer> count, GLTypeCT<T>* data) {
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, count *
      sizeof(data->stride), data, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
  }

  VertexBuffer& operator=(const VertexBuffer& other) = delete;
  VertexBuffer(const VertexBuffer& other) = delete;
private:
  Tags::VertexBuffer::internal handle_;
};

} //namespace GLLayer
} //namespace Spiky
```

And here is my main:

```
int main(int argc, char** args)
{


  GLTypeCT<GLfloat> quadVertices[] = {
    // Positions        // Texture Coords
    -1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f,
    1.0f,  1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,  -1.0f, 0.0f,
  };

  // Setup plane VAO
  glGenVertexArrays(1, &quadVAO);
  VertexBuffer buffer{};
  glBindVertexArray(quadVAO);
  buffer.Bind();
  VertexBuffer::BufferData(12, quadVertices);

  glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
  glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 3 * sizeof(GLfloat),
    (GLvoid*)(0));

  glBindVertexArray(0);

  auto RenderQuad = [&] {
    glBindVertexArray(quadVAO);
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4);
    glBindVertexArray(0);
  };

  //render calls later on...

}
```

Do you think the error comes from VertexBuffer ?

Comment: Where is that access violation located, according to the debugger? Also: make sure all your GL calls are succeeding (cfr. `glGetError`) and that cleanup is properly done (I see no unbinding for the VBO)

Comment: @Marco A1) VS tells me that the error comes from glDrawArrays() ; 2) by cout-ing glGeterror, I got error #1280; does this mean anything ?

Comment: @Gernot1976 nope; SDL2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see a few possible issues here.

But first, 1280 means GL_INVALID_ENUM, where did you get this? After which opengl call?

In this:

```
static void BindRequest(Tags::VertexBuffer::internal name = ZERO_BUFFER) {
if(_active != name) {
  glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
  _active = name;
}
```

You should probably pass `glBindBuffer` what you want to bind. `glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, name)`

I doubt this is causing it to crash but, when you call `glVertexAttribPointer` you're passing it `3 * sizeof(float)` when it should be `6 * sizeof(float)`, why? Because the stride should be the size of your entire "Vertex" which in your case contains the positions and texcoords, which sums up to 6 floats.

And when you're calling `glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4)` you're saying that the count is 4, but as far as I can tell it's only 2.

The "access violation at 0x00000000", you get that if the function pointer to that function hasn't been retrieved, what are you using to get those pointers? I saw in the comments that you use SDL but that won't do any of that for you. You could do it yourself or use GLEW.

Comment: 2) 3 * sizeof(float) is actually OK cause i only use vertex positions : it's for rendering a fullScreen quad, so I can simply call glFragCoord; but I left texCoords only for debug purposes :)

Comment: 3) Just a last question though; do you think it's a good idea to wrap a VertexBuffer into a class like that ? Do you have any suggestions to make it better ?

Comment: I usually don't do It but it's not a bad idea for that. To be honest it was a bit messy so you could improve that a bit, how? I'm afraid I can't help you with that :)